# ASP.NET MVC Form with Dynamic Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

**Problem**

I want to display a form that will have a variable amount of values. However each form item has to have a sort of key associated with it. For example, the form generates a name, username and occupation fields, I need to also have keys generated so when the form is submitted, the receiver method can tell what items are what.

**Attempted Solution**

Right now I have a list of FieldItems where a FieldItem is just a class with one class variable of a String. The solution works when populating the form, however on submission a list is returned and I can not tell which value belongs to which key. I was thinking about using a dictionary but I do not know how this would be accomplished in razor.

**View Model**

```
public class BuildReportViewModel
{
    public IList<BuildReportFieldItemViewModel> Fields { get; set; }
}
public class BuildReportFieldItemViewModel
{
    public string Field { get; set; }
}
```

**Editor for BuildReportFieldItemViewModel**

```
@model BuildReportFieldItemViewModel

<div class="editor-label">
    <label for="@Model.Field">@Model.Field</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    <input type="text" name="@Model.Field">
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a hidden key field

View Model

```
public class BuildReportViewModel
{
    public IList<BuildReportFieldItemViewModel> Fields { get; set; }
}
public class BuildReportFieldItemViewModel
{
    public string Field;
    public string Key;
}
```

Editor for BuildReportFieldItemViewModel

```
@model BuildReportFieldItemViewModel

<div class="editor-label">
    <label for="@Model.Field">@Model.Field</label>
</div>
<div class="editor-field">

    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Field)
    @Html.Hidden(Model.Key, "key_value");
</div>
```

Comment: probably best solution. You could use a GUID for your key since it isn't associated to any other data.